# Show that any rectangle $(a, b)\times (c, d)$ is open in $\mathbb R^2$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I can easily prove this for Euclidean metric.  But here the metric is not specified.
So I need a generalized proof for all metrics.
How do we start then?

Comment: I don't think this is true for arbitrary metrics.

Comment: I suspect the topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$ for this exercise is the usual Euclidean topology.  It is not true that every metric on the plane has these rectangles as "open" in the topological sense.

Comment: For arbitrary norms, it is immediate from the fact that all norms are equivalent in finite dimensions, though.

Comment: $\Bbb R^n$ without any further specification is almost always taken to be with the Euclidean norm / metric / topology (some times the Zariski topology, but not this time).

Comment: @hardmath any example?

Comment: @ClementC. I cannot understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: Your statement is true for every *norm* on $\mathbb{R}^2$ (but not for every *metric*). This former point follows from a theorem stating that [all norms are equivalent in finite-dimensional vector spaces](https://mathprelims.wordpress.com/2008/07/16/equivalence-of-norms-in-n-dimensions/), and thus the topologies they induce are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another example. Let $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be the bijection which fixes all points $p \in \mathbb{R}^2$ that are not equal to $(0,0)$ or $(2,0)$ but swaps those two points:
$$f(p) = \begin{cases}
p &\text{if $p \ne (0,0)$ and $p \ne (2,0)$} \\
(2,0) &\text{if $p = (0,0)$} \\
(0,0) &\text{if $p = (2,0)$}
\end{cases}
$$
Let $\mathcal{T}_1$ be the usual metric topology on Euclidean space, with metric denoted $d_1$.

Let $\mathcal{T}_2$ be the topology
$$\mathcal{T}_2 = \{f(U) \bigm| U \in \mathcal{T}_1\}
$$
which is also a metric topology: $d_2(p,q) = d_1(f^{-1}(p),f^{-1}(q))$.

The set $V=(-1,1) \times (-1,1)$ is open in $\mathcal{T}_1$. But it is not open in $\mathcal{T}_2$, because if $V=f(U)$ then
$$U = \bigl(V - \{(0,0)\}\bigr) \cup \{(2,0)\} \not\in \mathcal{T}_1
$$

Comment: Nicely presented!

Comment: I have just started topology,  so I am not able to digest this . This looks quite neat. But I am looking for some answer in metric space.  I want to find a point x which doesn't lie in any open ball. How can I do it? (Again, without involving topology! )

Comment: @divya: This answer *is* in a metric space. You requested for a generalized proof for all metrics on $\mathbb{R}^2$, and this answer (as well as the answer of hardmath) shows that your request is impossible, by giving a counterexample. Also, you'll find that in your study of metric spaces, concepts of topology are unavoidable: the collection of open subsets of the metric space *is*, by definition, the topology of tha metric space.

Comment: Ok. Then I think I should try to understand topology first. Anyways, this was helpful.

Comment: @divya: By the way, if you feel that either of the answers is acceptable to you as an answer to the question that you posed, then you should click the accept button on that answer.

Comment: Oh yes. I forgot.

Answer (score 2):

One way to give a metric topology on the plane in which not all rectangles $(a,b)\times (c,d)$ are open is by imposing a topology that makes the plane homeomorphic to the real line.  In greater detail:

We know that in Euclidean topologies $\mathbb{R}$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$.  For example, removing a point separates the real line, but does not separate the plane.

However we do have $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ of equal cardinality, so let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a one-to-one correspondence.   Let $\tau$ be the metric topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ induced by this correspondence with the usual metric on $\mathbb{R}$.  Thus $f$ is continuous with respect to the topology $\tau$ on the plane.

If all rectangles $(a,b)\times (c,d)$ in the plane were open in the metric topology $\tau$, then the identity map $id:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ with respect to the topology $\tau$ on the domain and the usual topology on the codomain would be continuous and injective.

It follows by [invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain)  that the composition of maps $id(f)$ would be a homeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Contradiction.